# Using libssl with nmake

Tags: openssl, nmake

```
    LIBS =   ws2_32.lib winmm.lib advapi32.lib  crypt32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib   libeay32.lib ssleay32.lib 

OSCOMPAT = /DWIN32 /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400
VSCOMPAT = /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE  
CFLAGS= -I . -I$C /MT /W3 $(OSCOMPAT) $(VSCOMPAT) -nologo $(EXTRACFLAGS)

test: $(CCLIENTLIB) test.obj oauth.obj hash.obj oauth_http.obj xmalloc.obj 
    LINK /NOLOGO mtest.obj oauth.obj hash.obj oauth_http.obj xmalloc.obj  $(LIBS) 


test.obj:test.c 
oauth.obj: oauth.c
hash.obj: hash.c
oauth_http.obj: oauth.h oauth_http.c
xmalloc.obj: xmalloc.c
```

I am getting following errors

```
    LINK /NOLOGO test.obj oauth.obj hash.obj oauth_http.obj xmalloc.obj    ws2_32.lib winmm.lib advapi32.lib  crypt32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib   libeay32.lib ssleay32.lib
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HMAC referenced in function oauth_sign_hmac_sha1_raw
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_sha1 referenced in function oauth_sign_hmac_sha1_raw
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_free referenced in function oauth_sign_rsa_sha1
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol CRYPTO_free referenced in function oauth_sign_rsa_sha1
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_SignFinal referenced in function oauth_sign_rsa_sha1
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_DigestUpdate referenced in function oauth_sign_rsa_sha1
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_DigestInit referenced in function oauth_sign_rsa_sha1
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_size referenced in function oauth_sign_rsa_sha1
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol BIO_free referenced in function oauth_sign_rsa_sha1
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey referenced in function oauth_sign_rsa_sha1
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol BIO_new_mem_buf referenced in function oauth_sign_rsa_sha1
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup referenced in function oauth_verify_rsa_sha1
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_VerifyFinal referenced in function oauth_verify_rsa_sha1
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY referenced in function oauth_verify_rsa_sha1
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol X509_free referenced in function oauth_verify_rsa_sha1
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol X509_get_pubkey referenced in function oauth_verify_rsa_sha1
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol PEM_read_bio_X509 referenced in function oauth_verify_rsa_sha1
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_DigestFinal referenced in function oauth_body_hash_file
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_MD_size referenced in function oauth_body_hash_file
hash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_MD_CTX_init referenced in function oauth_body_hash_file
test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 20 unresolved externals
```

what is the problem in make file . 
**how to link libssl with my app ?**

you can download code from here 
https://rapidshare.com/files/458792519/test.rar
(it includes code from liboauth )

Comment: Are you getting any compiler errors (or only link errors)?  The PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey symbol, for example, seems a bit odd to show up as an unresolved symbol.  In the version of OpenSSL I am using, it only exists as a macro defined to call PEM_ASN1_read_bio.  So it doesn't seem it should be showing up as an unresolved symbol.  It makes me wonder if you are including the correct headers.  The version I am using, though, could be different than yours.

Comment: @Mark I am only getting link error.

Comment: @Vivek:  I'm unsure then what the issue is.  Just as a sanity check, you might run `dumpbin /exports libeay32.lib` (and ssleay32.lib) to make sure that they actually have the function definitions in them.

Comment: @Mark Wilkins I checked with that tool and the symbols are defined. 
I am attaching full code in my new comment.

Comment: hi I uploaded my make file lib and code at https://rapidshare.com/files/458792519/test.rar

Comment: @Vivek:  I did download that file this weekend, but I don't have anything on my home laptop that would decompress a .rar file.  And, to be honest, I wasn't terribly motivated to dig into a >1MB compressed project.  If you could reproduce the problem with a simple 10 line program and small make file that you can post, you might get more responses.  Another possibility would be to add a bounty to the question; that might bring about more interest from other people.

Comment: @Mark Wilkins , file size is 1 mb because it contains the lib files. 
I will try with your suggestion. 
to start bounty and upload a zip file.

Comment: @Vivek:  I downloaded it and ran "nmake -f makefile.nt".  I had to add user32.lib and gdi32.lib to your LIBS statement in makefile.nt and then it linked cleanly.  I tried it with Visual Studio 2005, 2008, and 2010.  So my guess is that you have your path set up incorrectly.  You need to run the batch file that sets up the environment for the command line tools (e.g., vcvars32.bat).  It could be that it is using the wrong linker or possibly the wrong compiler.

Comment: @Mark Wikins a lot of thanks . adding user32 and gdi32 . it worked. 

can you please post it as answer. so I can accept your answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the conversation in the comments on the OP, I downloaded the example code and ran nmake against it (makefile.nt).  I did get linker errors but the missing symbols were from Win32 libs.  I added user32.lib and gdi32.lib to the LIBS list in the makefile and it then linked cleanly (the build worked with VS2005, VS2008, and VS2010).

As the OP points out, it also linked cleanly when adding those two additional libraries.  It is not clear to me how that would help resolve those symbols from libeay32.lib.  So my suspicion is that the change to the make file resulted in a full rebuild and compile of all .obj files.  The full clean build resulted in it working.  So maybe (I'm just guessing) the .obj files were compiled incorrectly originally (compiler that didn't work well with the linker perhaps?) and the full rebuild made everything consistent.

Comment: It was not building with clean build without using those two libs.

Comment: @Vivek:  It's a bit of a puzzle to me, but I'm glad you got it working.  Those types of problems are some of the least fun to deal with in programming.